# Data load from Amazon S3 to Redshift using Copy Command - How to store Time of copy in Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I am using Amazon Firehose to stream online data, apply transformation using Lambda and load data to Redshift through S3. The COPY command in Firehose is:

```
COPY <TABLE NAME> FROM 's3 Location' CREDENTIALS 'IAM ROLE' MANIFEST json 'auto' gzip;
```

I am interested in knowing the exact time at which the S3 to Redshift copy is made by Firehose, so that I can store the same in Redshift and use it for future references. How do I get the time while doing copy command?

Example: If I have a Data Pipeline job, I will get `sysdate` and then  insert it into the Redshift table. How can I accomplish something similar to this in S3 to Redshift Copy? Is there any direct option or workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already using an AWS Lambda function to perform [Amazon Kinesis Firehose Data Transformation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/data-transformation.html), you should have the Lambda function add the date. This will then flow through to the data being loaded via the `COPY` command.

Comment: Thanks for the reply john. I am interested in knowing the below timings at different points of the data transformations and load during the data flow in streams. 1. What time it came to kinesis stream - Stream Date and Time. 2. Lambda Function Invocation Time - Lambda Run Time 3. What time data is loaded to Redshift from s3 - Data Load time. By this way i can track the time delays at exact intervals and keep in redshift for future references. I have done 1 and 2, however for the Data load time, i am kind of lost. Your help on this would be appreciated. Thanks again.

Comment: For data load times, you should consult the [STL_LOAD_COMMITS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_STL_LOAD_COMMITS.html) table, but it might be a bit hard to match it to every Firehose load.

Comment: I got a reply from AWS Support team, that i should be using default column with sysdate or current_time while doing create table so that when firehose does a copy the column is updated with current time.

Comment: Ooh! That's clever. You could pass it as NULL, having the default override it, or add a column at the end that isn't in your import file, which will get the Default value.

Answer (score 0):

I got a reply from AWS Support team, that i should be using default column with sysdate or current_time while doing create table so that when firehose does a copy, the column is updated with current time by copy command itself.

Comment: Hey Keerthi, I simply want to take the data from S3 and dump it to Redshift. Currently using a manual copy using SQL WorkBench/J, how can I automate this using AWS Lambda Python3.6?